# Holt-Winters Damped Method in SAS?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, sas

Is there a way to implement the Holt-Winters Damped Method in SAS?  In the documentation for PROC ESM it details how to use the Winters Additive and Multiplicative methods but no mention of also incorporating dampening.